# ActionBarSherlock Custom MenuItem Divider

Tags: android, menuitem, actionbarsherlock, divider

First, I want to say that I have modified the method **needsDividerBefore** and now the divider appeared between menu items. However, I want to customize this divider and I tried all the ways mentioned before but I could not succeed.

Second, the divider I want is as same as foursquare, twitter and instagram used. Is this a common divider or all these applications use a custom layout? I don't know but even if they use custom layouts, I want to add action buttons from menu.xml and how can I customize divider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Modifying that method will only affect pre-ICS phones so you will still get the natural divider behavior on ICS+. This means that your app will look differently based on what version of Android is running it.
2. You can change the divider with the `actionBarDivider` theme attribute.

Comment: Thank you Jack for your reply. I want to ask one more thing; my phone's Android version is Froyo and foursquare or instagram has a divider whose height is same as ActionBar. However, the height of my divider is same as the Tab Navigation. How can I also change the height of divider between menu items?

Comment: Also, is there a possibility to have space between top bar and tabs in ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: No. ActionBarSherlock is only a backport of the ICS action bar so it can only do things that the native action bar can do.

Comment: Hi Jack again me, sorry for this. actionBarDivider attribute provides both the divider between tabs and the divider between menu items. Therefore, the height of divider between menu items is same as the height of divider between menu items. However, as far as I know Foursquare uses ActionBarSherlock and the height of divider between menu items is different than the height of divider between tabs. How can I make the divider between menu items much more great as Foursquare did?

Comment: They add the divider to the action item background drawable and do not use the regular dividers.

Comment: I know I'm exhausting you but could you please check my answer?

Comment: You can download the Foursquare .apk and decompress it to get a general idea about how they made its implementation. As Jake said, they're overriding the actionBarItemBackground background style.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find background attribute in MenuItem. This is the xml for MenuItem

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu"
    android:title="menu"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
</item>
```

And then I added

`android:actionLayout="@layout/divider"`

And the divider.xml is below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp" /></LinearLayout>
```

When I use this, the icon is unvisible. What is the best way to add a custom divider?

Comment: An action item's background is specified on the theme using the `actionBarItemBackground` attribute. If you use a 9-patch for the drawables you can create the effect of having a divider on every action item.

Comment: In that way, the pressed background of action items are invisible. Also, I use a custom icon and actionBarItemBackground attribute affects the background of icon.